# MongoDB aggregate/grouping by key-value pairs

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data looks something like this:

```
    { 
            "_id" : "9aa072e4-b706-47e6-9607-1a39e904a05a", 
            "customerId" : "2164289-4", 
            "channelStatuses" : {
                    "FOO" : {
                    "status" : "done"
                    }, 
                    "BAR" : {
                    "status" : "error"
                    }
            }, 
            "channel" : "BAR", 
    }
```

My aggregate/group looks like this:

```
    { 
            "_id" : {
                    "customerId" : "$customerId", 
                    "channel" : "$channel", 
                    "status" : "$channelStatuses[$channel].status"
            }, 
                    "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1
            }
    }
```

So basically with the example data the group should give me a group grouped by:

```
   {"customerId": "2164289-4", "channel": "BAR", "status": "error"}
```

But I cannot use []-indexing in a aggregate/group. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the result you want with the current structure using `.aggregate()`. You "could" change the structure to use an array rather than named keys, and the operation is actually quite simple.

So with a document like:

```js
    { 
            "_id" : "9aa072e4-b706-47e6-9607-1a39e904a05a", 
            "customerId" : "2164289-4", 
            "channelStatuses" : [
                {
                    "channel": "FOO",
                    "status" : "done"
                }, 
                {
                    "channel": "BAR",
                    "status" : "error"
                }
            ], 
            "channel" : "BAR", 
    }
```

You can then do in modern releases with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt):

```js
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "customerId" : "$customerId", 
            "channel" : "$channel", 
            "status": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": { "$filter": {
                            "input": "$chanelStatuses",
                            "as": "el", 
                            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.channel", "$channel" ] }
                        }},
                        "as": "el",
                        "in": "$$el.status"
                    }},
                    0
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
```

Older versions of MongoDB are going to going to require `$unwind` to access the matched array element.

In MongoDB 2.6 then you can still "pre-filter" the array before unwind:

```js
[
    { "$project": {
        "customerId": 1,
        "channel": 1,
        "status": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$channelStatuses",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.channel", "$channel" ] },
                            "$$el.status",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$status" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "customerId": "$customerId",
            "channel": "$channel",
            "status": "$status"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]
```

And anything prior to that you "filter" after `$unwind` instead:

```js
[
    { "$unwind": "$channelStatuses" },
    { "$project": {
        "customerId": 1,
        "channel": 1,
        "status": "$channelStatuses.status",
        "same": { "$eq": [ "$channelStatuses.status", "$channel" ] }
    }},
    { "$match": { "same": true } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "customerId": { "$first": "$customerId" },
        "channel": { "$first": "$channel" },
        "status": { "$first": "$status" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "customerId": "$customerId",
            "channel": "$channel",
            "status": "$status"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]
```

In a lesser version than MongoDB 2.6 you also need to `$project` the result of the equality test between the two fields and then `$match` on the result in a seperate stage. You might also note the "two" `$group` stages, since the first one removes any possible duplicates of the `"channel"` values after the filter via the `$first` accumulators. The following `$group` is exactly the same as in the previous listing.

But if you cannot change the structure and need "flexible" matching of keys where you cannot supply every name, then you must use mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
       emit({
           "customerId": this.customerId,
           "channel": this.channel,
           "status": this.channelStatuses[this.channel].status
       },1);
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum(values);
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Where of course you can use that sort of notation

Comment: Thanks for this. I decided to change channelStatuses into an array like you described. Is there an easier way to do the getting of the proper channel, lets say first unwinding the channelStatuses and then doing a match ("channelStatuses.channel" : "$channels"), and then just grouping by status?

Comment: @Keksike The whole point of operations like `$filter` and `$map` are to "avoid" using `$unwind`. The `$unwind` operator is a "huge" performance hog by the nature of what it does. Unless you intend to aggregate across documents from values contained within an array you should be avoiding `$unwind`. You can do the same thing, but it is far more costly. The best way is the one that is shown.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to do the grouping without arrayElemAt, as the mongodb-version I'm using doesn't support it?

Comment: @Keksike What do you have? MongoDB 2.6.x at least?

Comment: @Keksike Added everything.